# Get vertical to horizontal listing from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

I have imported some data from a dataframe. [excel](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AieO48E0rWr2lTVYAHYu6C31AMAh)

```
import pandas as pd

ExcelPrincipal = pd.ExcelFile('calculus.xlsx')

DEntr = ExcelPrincipal.parse('Hoja1')

idr = []
for i in range(len(DEntr)):
    idr.append([DEntr.values[i][0],DEntr.values[i][1],DEntr.values[i][2],
                DEntr.values[i][7],DEntr.values[i][8],DEntr.values[i][9]])

print('The list is: ','\n',idr)
```

Using the code I made I manage to pass them to the list, but horizontally, obtaining the following result:

```
[[1, 'CC', 1, 2.5, 0, 0], [2, 'CC', 1, 2.5, 0, 0], [3, 'CC', 2, 2.5, 0, 0], [ 4, 'VV', 1, 4.0, -2200, -1000], [5, 'VV', 2, 5.0, -2200, -1000]]
```

But what I really want is for my dataframe columns to print horizontally, something like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ['CC', 'CC', 'CC', 'VV', 'VV'], [1, 1, 2, 1, 2], [2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 4, 5], [0, 0, 0, -2200, -2200], [0, 0, 0, -1000, -1000]]
```

I greatly appreciate their respective contributions, best regards.

Comment: Are you looking for the [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) method?

Comment: Alternatively, if it's no longer in the form of a dataframe, `zip(*idr)` should do the trick as well for rotating a 2-dimensional list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to me you care about the dataframe because it should be in a good shape according to your code.

What I see you want is to do a *transpose* on the list. So instead of:

```
print('The list is: ','\n',idr)
```

do this:

```
print('The list is: ','\n',list(zip(*idr)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'CC', 1, 2.5, 0, 0], [2, 'CC', 1, 2.5, 0, 0], [3, 'CC', 2, 2.5, 0, 0], [ 4, 'VV', 1, 4.0, -2200, -1000], [5, 'VV', 2, 5.0, -2200, -1000]]).T
```

output:

```
     0    1    2      3      4
0    1    2    3      4      5
1   CC   CC   CC     VV     VV
2    1    1    2      1      2
3  2.5  2.5  2.5      4      5
4    0    0    0  -2200  -2200
5    0    0    0  -1000  -1000
```